# Java: Splitting Integer into 2 Bytes and then combining them again into an Integer

Tags: java, arrays, integer

i'm currently working on a project that sends data from a java application through a serial port to an arduino.

The problem i have is the following, i need to split an Integer into 2 bytes and then combine them into an Integer in Arduino. But the other way around (Arduino->java) only causes trouble for me.
The arduino part isn't that hard and works like a charm, but despite me looking through the relevant Questions&Answers already posted on here, i can't quite work out how to combine the bytes correctly together into an int.

Here's the java code that just refuses to work :

```
int in = 500;
byte[] data = new byte[2];

data[0] = (byte)(in & 0xFF);
data[1] = (byte)((in >> 8) & 0xFF);

int res = data[0] | (data[1] << 8);
```

The console print out i get from this is:

```
data[0] = -12  
data[1] = 1  
res = -12
```

but i need res to be 500!

Comment: An int is made of 4 bytes though...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to store 5 in `data[0]`, 0 in `data[0]`. What about the other 0. Shouldn't it be `byte[3]`?

Comment: The problem is that you downcast to use a `byte[]`. If you use a `short[]` or an `int[]` it would work as expected

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java uses *signed bytes* (C, C++, C# operate with *unsigned* ones), so you should take care of *complement representations* (for negative values):

```
int in = 500; 
byte[] data = new byte[2]; // <- assuming "in" value in 0..65535 range and we can use 2 bytes only

data[0] = (byte)(in & 0xFF);
data[1] = (byte)((in >> 8) & 0xFF);

int high = data[1] >= 0 ? data[1] : 256 + data[1];
int low = data[0] >= 0 ? data[0] : 256 + data[0];

int res = low | (high << 8);
```

Comment: Thanks, best answer I've found. I'll give +2 if I could.

Comment: Precious code. Saved my day!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is happening here:

```
int res = data[0] | (data[1] << 8);
```

The `|` operator requires `int` operands, and `data[0]` is being promoted from a `byte` to an `int`.  But since both `byte` and `int` are signed types, that promotion is turning the byte `-12` into the integer `-12` .... by sign extension.

The simplest fix is this:

```
int res = (data[0] & 0xff) | ((data[1] & 0xff) << 8);
```

---

There is another problem here too.  In general, you can't represent an `int` as 2 bytes.  The `int` type is 32 bits wide, and requires 4 bytes ... to represent the entire range.

Comment: concerning your edit: yes, i'm aware, but i do not need the entire range of the Integer, because Integers on Arduino are 2 bytes. i'm not planning to send anything bigger than what 2 bytes can represent.

Comment: You should consider using a Java `short` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought too, but i wanted to see if it works with Integers as well.

Comment: You will get the same issues (wrt sign extension) for `short` and `int`.  The only difference will be that you need to cast the expression to a `short`.  Java's bitwise `&`, `|` and `^` operators are only defined as `int, int -> int` or `long, long -> long`.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is just to use [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html):

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
buf.putShort(500);
byte[] result = buf.array(); // [-12, 1]

buf = ByteOrder.wrap(result);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
short res = buf.getShort(); // 500
```

This have the advantages:

- Integration with Java IO - you don't need to get the arrays - you can just pass it directly to channels.
- Explicit specification of ordering
- It's in the standard library since Java 1.4

Answer (score -1):

If you use Guava already (which you should), [this problem is already solved.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toByteArray%28int%29)